# Invert Colors code python CodeHs not working properly as intended

Tags: python, computer-science, karel, codesite

My code works, but the site doesn't accept it, is there something visibly wrong in my code.

```
alreadypainted = 0
while front_is_clear():
    if color_is(color["red"]):
        paint("blue")
        move()
    if color_is(color["blue"]):
        paint("red")
        move()
if front_is_blocked():
    if color_is(color["red"]):
        paint("blue")
        alreadypainted += 1
    if color_is(color["blue"]) and alreadypainted < 1:
        paint("red")
```

BTW, all this is for my Python high school class, that is why I'm using codeHs, and that's why there is predefined functions.

I am inverting the colors correctly, but the site isn't accepting the code.

[image]

⬇this is a video of me running the code on the site⬇

https://streamable.com/c6xww3

Comment: Should the second `if` in both cases be `elif`?  If you paint the red cell blue, isn't the second `if` going to immediately paint it back to red?

Comment: Tried didnt work

Comment: Well, you haven't shown us the assignment, so we have no idea what you're supposed to do or why the answer wouldn't be accepted.

Comment: I did i am soppused to make karrel inverse the colors

Comment: Clearly, that's not the assignment, because it's rejecting the very first point.  For example, what does "inverse" mean?  The "inverse" of red is cyan, not blue.